# How to check that ReadFileEx ended loading without sleeping thread?

Tags: file, winapi, file-io, asynchronous

I used winapi ReadFileEx to load 30 megabyte array asynchronously
and holy shit it works perfectly good - i have got whole reading 
for free, no slowdown of my calculations just array is magically 
loaded in background and none slowdown of game frames (though I
use 1 core computer)

But the question is like that - as far as i know to receive
an "reading finished" call I should sleep my thread, I do not 
want to do it, I just fired load_asynchronusly from my main 
thread then want to know when it finished (by now all load works
this way I just not receive my callback call when it is finished)

I can test the content of loaded array in time and check 
if for example last bythes with "check if this is overvritten"
are overwritten then I will know but this is maybe not so 
safe (?) Is there any way to determine when it finished 
in a simple  way close to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Call [`GetOverlappedResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683209.aspx) to test asynchronously whether the operation has completed.
2. Pass a [`FileIOCompletionRoutine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364052.aspx). That will be executed when the read completes.
3. Use the event in the [`OVERLAPPED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684342.aspx) structure. That is signaled when the read completes.

Comment: Much tnx, :) I will chceck it! I also think that maybe if i substitute sleep into sleepEx in my grame loop It will be also working - I can do that couse I just do not wont to create no any new therad other than the main one (mislooked that i probably sleep the main thread for a very short period and hopefully maybe it will work , tnx